# Columns children cannot return null, but returning would stop the loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to iterate through a list and produce a widget (Text) for now for each 'step' in the list.

When printing I get exactly as expected, however, I get the error `Column's children must not contain any null values, but a null value was found at index 0`.

Which I understand as I am not returning anything. But if I do return something the loop stops, so I just get the first step.

```
recipeMethodList(recipeMethod) {
for (var step in recipeMethod) {
  stepNumber = stepNumber + 1;
  Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('$stepNumber. $step'),
    ],
  );
  print('$stepNumber. $step');
}
```

I call this with:

```
Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[recipeMethodList(recipeMethod)],
            ),
```

Comment: I have seen this before, however I always get type differences.

type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by building a new list. One which contains widgets of my choosing. Then returning that list to the builder.

```
    methodCard(recipeMethod, context) {
    List<Padding> methodList = [];
    for (var step in recipeMethod) {
      stepNumber++;
      methodList.add(
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), color: Colors.white),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                  child: Text(
                    '$stepNumber. $step',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontFamily: 'NotoSans',
                        color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return methodList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the function like

```
List<Widget> recipeMethodList(List recipeMethod) {
  int stepNumber=0;
  return recipeMethod.map((step) {
    stepNumber = stepNumber + 1;
    return Text('$stepNumber. $step');
  }).toList();
}
```